# TeX capacity exceeded when calling LuaLaTeX

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external, memory

I am using recently updated MacTex Distribution 2016 on a MacBook Pro Mid 2009 and Texmaker is my editor. I want to include a phase portrait created with `matlab2tikz` with a lot of lines. Reducing the samples is no option since it reduces quality and I can see kinks in the lines... So I get the well known error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
```

Since I want to avoid to change memory allocation hard bounds I use lualatex in the system call with `\tikzset`. See my MWE below and the [phase_portrait.tex](https://we.tl/qJ6ORx0ZTJ)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}

\begin{document}
\input{phase_portrait.tex}
\end{document}
```

I run the file with

```
 "pdflatex" --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

and it doesn't work and I get the same error. Why do I still get it? even though I call `Lualatex` which has dynamic memory allocation? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

My versions are respectively:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.7.11)

This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)  (format=lualatex 2016.7.11)
```

---

EDIT: For me I solved the issue now by compiling my whole document with LuaLaTeX. But this is still not the answer I was looking for since now I am forced to compile with LuaLaTeX. So there is further interest in a solution to the problem ;)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! 3Mb for a `.tex` is too much in my opinion, have you conside to split it, and then call files somehow, like putting data in a single file?

Comment: Hey! Well not really considered that since it works fine when I compile the whole file with LuaLaTex. How do you mean exactly splitting it? In the end it must be compiled in one go, no?

Comment: I don't know exactly I am not used to tikz http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51226/92620 but in my opinion a 3MB file containning both data and commands is too much i think there is some other ways to manage a project in a simpler way by spliting it on several files using `\input \include` and so on.

Comment: Yeah I know the externalization option, which puts any figure into one separate (compiled) file, thats exactly the case I have here. Compiling fails on one figure in the MWE. Therefore I want to use LuaLaTex in the system call fashion since it allows for larger files and works if I call the whole file with it.

Answer (score 1):

I also deleted the `row sep=crcr` options and all `\\` line endings and also
got a picture with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error 
%    -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}

\begin{document}
    \input{Downloads/phase_portrait.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

lualatex on

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}   


\begin{document}
\input{phase_portrait.tex}
\end{document}
```

runs fine and produces

[image]

If you want to externalize, you could produce a standalone latex file, compile that, and include the pdf in your document as an image.

Comment: Hey JPi, yeah it works also for me with LuaLaTeX, but I want to compile my document with PdfLaTeX since when I use LuaLaTeX I have problems with externalize, see the other thread I opened: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318906/lualatex-fails-on-tikzexternalize-on-very-easy-mwe) `Link`. So the question would still be on how to run it in system call mode.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but you can achieve what you want as follows:  Compile this standalone graph in lualatex, which produces a pdf, then include it as a pdf image in the main document, which you compile with pdflatex.