# LuaLaTex fails on Tikzexternalize on very easy MWE

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, tikz-external

I am using recently updated MacTex Distribution 2016 on a MacBook Pro Mid 2009 and Texmaker is my editor. I searched a long time for a solution to this problem but nothing really helped, so I give it another shot here! I must be missing something simple, since the very easy MWE won't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I run on pdflatex

```
"pdflatex" --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

it works like a charm. However when I run LuaLaTeX

```
"lualatex" --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

it gives error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{m
ain}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'main-figure0' (expec
ted one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system c
alls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also name
d 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error
messages can be found in 'main-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to t
ypeset the picture.
See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
```

Why is that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compiles fine for me with lualatex.  Try updating your system.  (Tried to include version list, but is too long for comment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No doubt the packages will get updated to current luatex at some point, but until then:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85,shellesc}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```